# How MVC View works even without specifying Model type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Just created a simple `MVC 5` application.

Created a controller and calling my view like this:

```
var testClass = new TestClass();
testClass.Name = "Krish";
return View(testClass);
```

Created a view and it looks  like below:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<h3>@Model.Name</h3>
```

***But this just works even without specifying the Model type.***

---

```
Should not we specify something like:
`@Model TestClass`
```

---

Any ideas why?

**EDIT:**
[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505255(v=vs.118).aspx) page of MSDN says that `Represents a container that is used to pass strongly typed data between a controller and a view.` We are not strongly typing the model above. How come then the view find the model type then ?

Comment: it can work this way, but recommended approach is to strongly type your view, if you pass some other type model your view will fail

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: No. As long as I pass other models with the property `Name`, it works fine.

Comment: yes but if you pass with some other model which does not have Name property then exception will be thrown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cshtml view (or vbhtml if you're that way inclined) is actually turned into a .NET class which inherits from `WebViewPage<TModel>`.

When you declare in a view

```
@model SomeType
```

your telling the MVC framework to declare your view like so:

```
public class _Page_Path_To_MyView_cshtml : WebViewPage<SomeType> { ... }
```

When you omit the `@model` declaration, the framework declares your view like this:

```
public class _Page_Path_To_MyView_cshtml : WebViewPage<dynamic> { ... }
```

Effectively all Views without a `@model` declaration can be thought of as having

```
@model dynamic
```

at the top, which is why your `@Model.Name` still works, though you will notice that won't have intellisense (unless you use it more than once).

If you did `@Model.SomePropertyThatDoesntExist` you'll get an exception.

Comment: When I navigate and see the `Model type`, it is `public TModel Model { get; }`. It is not dynamic ?

Comment: `TModel` will be `dynamic` unless you tell it otherwise (by using `@model XXX`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And about `TModel` ? What is it actually? Where can I find more information about it ?

Comment: @dav_i can you tell some book or article where we can read in detail the ``WebViewPage`` and ``TModel`` for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

It can work this way, but it is convention that View should be strongly typed.let's understand this with an example.

Suppose you have two models:

```
public class Model1
{
public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Model2
{
public string FullName {get;set;}
}
```

Now if you have this in View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<h3>@Model.Name</h3>
```

and from action you do:

```
var Model= new Model1();
Model.Name = "Ehsan";
return View(Model);
```

All will be fine, but if you pass like this:

```
var Model= new Model2();
Model.FullName = "Ehsan Sajjad";
return View(Model);
```

now you view will throw exception because this Model does not have `Name` property.

Comment: Thanks. But when i see the type of `@Model`, it is `public TModel Model { get; }`. What is `TModel` ? Is it `dynamic` ?